# Equation of torus: stucked in removing one variable

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to write the equation of torus by keeping in mind the following figure:

Here circle is unit circle whose revolution around z-axis gives the right torus. Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be arbitrary point on torus,  $Q=(x,y,0)$ the projection of $P$ into $XY$ plane. Let $C=(x',y',0)$ the center of moving circle. Then

(1) Distance of $P$ from $C$ is $1$ which is expressed by $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z^2=1.$

(2) Distance of $C$ from origin is $2$, so 
$x'^2+y'^2=4.$

(3) The points $O$, $C$ and $Q$ are colinear. Hence 
$xy'=yx'. $

From these thre equations, I was unable to obtain a single equation involving $x,y,z$, namely 
$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2=1.$$

**Question:** How to obtain last equation from (1),(2),(3)? Am I missing something more for it? From (1) and (2) we get $x^2-2xx'+y^2-2yy'+z^2+4=1.$ Now how to remove $x',y'$ from this using (3)? We can remove one, but how both can be removed? So am I missing any more equation?

(Note that the question of equation of torus is appeared previously, but without following *answer* of that, I was following picture below and trying in above way to obtain equation; so this is not duplicate of previous questions similar to this.)

[image]

Comment: I would simply argue as follows. $|OQ|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $|CQ|=|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2|.$ By Pythagoras you want $1=|CP|^2=z^2+|CQ|^2$. Need to think about what you are missing, if anything?? IOW, a good question.

Comment: This (your comment) is almost the same thing I saw later in answer to similar question but I was not following it, I was thinking how to obtain equation from given figure.

Comment: May be you should rewrite the collinearity condition using the dot product as follows
$$xx'+yy'=\vec{OC}\cdot\vec{OQ}=|OQ|\cdot |OP|=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: If you expand $\sqrt{(x'^2+y'^2)(x^2+y^2)}$ you can simplify the mixed terms using your equation $xy'=x'y$ to conclude the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You introduced two superfluous variables $x'$, $y'$, together with two extra equations, and now you face a horrible elimination problem. There are a lot of pitfalls here, e.g., introducing fallacious solutions, even if you find a trick to eliminate $x'$ and $y'$.

I propose the following procedure: There is this meridian circle $C_{\rm mer}$ living in the "virtual" $(\rho, z)$ right half plane, whereby $\rho:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Its equation is
$$C_{\rm mer}:\quad (\rho-2)^2+z^2=1\ .\tag{1}$$
This circle is rotated around the $z$-axis and in this way produces your torus $T$. A point $(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb R}^3$ has cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z)$ given by 
$$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad\phi={\rm arg}(x,y),\quad z=z$$
(we don't need to bother about the expression for $\phi$ here). This point lies on $T$ iff the resulting $\rho$ satisfies the equation $(1)$:
$$\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2\bigr)^2+z^2=1\ .$$